# Symfony2 error with xcache

Tags: php, symfony, xcache

I just installed xcache on my server (Fedora 16) following the tutorial on http://xcache.lighttpd.net/wiki/InstallFromSource.

When I try to run my Symfony2 app I get the following error:

```
Cannot redeclare class AppKernel
```

When I disable xcache, then Symfony2 is working perfectly again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because I had APC already installed, and there is apparently a conflict between xcache and apc